# Chartjs v2.7 - combo chart with time-series (financial) data; bar width's are irregular

Tags: javascript, chart.js

So I had some issues with previous versions of Chartjs (namely 2.5) when I was working with a combo chart (bar + line) and had difficulties with time-series data.

For context, I'm using financial data (stock price and volume). Since the market is only open 5 days a week, there is a "gap" in the data. I don't worry too much about this gap, but when using Chartjs's re-written functionality for time-series data, the width of the bars becomes irregular. Here's an example:

[image: Irregular Bars]

You can see that each "Friday" and "Monday" of data, the bars get larger to compensate for the gap. The `xAxes` code that creates this is:

```
type: 'time',
       time: {
       unit: 'day',
       distribution: 'linear'
       }
```

....

Now if I remove the `type: time` distinction, I get the standard bars, but the labels are pulling straight from my data, rather than being parsed as dates and correctly managed by Moment.js:

[image: Correct bars but wrong dates]

....

**To sum it up: how can I get regular-spaced bars when my data is not regularly linear while utilizing Chartjs's time-series axises?**

Answer (score 0):

This was addressed in a bug fix and merged as a part of the v2.8 release of Chartjs ([see here](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/pull/4994)).